# Dialog too large for netbook's 800 x 480 resolution

Tags: c#, winforms, resolution

I've designed a winforms dialog that is too large for a netbook's 800 x 480 resolution.

How can I fix that the dialog is shown properly. Is there a simple way that avoids a complete redesign?

Here's a screenshot of my problem: http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/2449/allgemeina.jpg

Comment: can you post a screenshot with the general layout?

Comment: What netbook is this? I have never one with such a low res.

Comment: added a screenshot. it's an Asus Eee PC 4G 701 with 7 inch display 800 x 480)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at this thread:

[Windows Forms resolution problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069694/winform-resolution-problem)

Answer (score 2):

The question that you should be asking is..

Do I really need to have all of the form fields displayed at the same time?

If not, how about breaking it down into sub-groups and placing each group onto a separate tab?

I second @p.campbell in asking for a screenshot.

Comment: Now that you've added a screenshot, I'd still say that tabs are a good idea. Effectively, the icons down the left are acting as tabs as, I guess, the dialog contents change as you click on each icon - whether you simply add more icons (with more specific purposes) to the left hand panel, or add real tabs to each page that is too large, is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps take a stab at redesigning your dialog. Perhaps consider:

- using tabs
- moving some information out of the dialog
- using scrollbars

Answer (score 0):

If netbooks are not used much by your users, so you just need your software to work on them rather than to be nice, you could enable [AutoScroll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll.aspx) on the Form/Dialog, or use a one or more [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) controls with AutoScroll enabled.

You will then need to check the screan size and set the size of the dialog to be no bigger then the screan before showing it.